# Error: SMTP AUTH is required for message submission on port 587

Tags: phpmailer, smtp-auth

```
    <?php
    require("../PHPMailer_5.2.4/class.phpmailer.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object

    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 587; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = '*******@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = '*******';
    $mail->setFrom('*******@gmail.com');

    $mail->Subject = "Test";
    $mail->Body = "hello";
    $mail->addAddress("*******@gmail.com");
    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else
    {
       echo "Message has been sent";
    }

    ?>
```

Gives the following Error:
SMTP -> ERROR: Password not accepted from server: 535 Incorrect authentication data
SMTP -> ERROR: RCPT not accepted from server: 550 SMTP AUTH is required for message submission on port 587
SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: ****@gmail.com Mailer Error: SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: ****@gmail.com
SMTP server error: SMTP AUTH is required for message submission on port 587

Comment: You're using a really old PHPMailer. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and use the gmail example provided, then read the docs if you're still having trouble. If you set `SMTPDebug = 2` you'll see why gmail doesn't like your login.

Comment: It looks like the `$mail->SMTPAuth = true;` doesn't really work. I have used the very same configuration for an e-mail server that does not require authentication and it worked fine.